# Не устанавливается grub при установке ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Устанавливаю ubuntu с флешки. При установке выбираю стереть диск и установить. Я так понимаю при этом варианте все нужные разделы должны создаться самостоятельно. Диск на ноуте один, других ОС не установлено.

В конце установки получаю ошибку, что не удалось установить GRUB в /target/.

Гугление говорит о том, что вероятно не создан загрузочный раздел, но я так понимаю, что это актуально только при ручной разметке диска. Как быть?

Comment: Всегда устанавливай разделы вручную. Автоматической установке присущи ошибки различного рода.

Comment: @cooleck Да вот что-то ни так ни так не ставится